# Can xargs' default delimiter be changed?

Tags: command-line, whitespace, xargs

I want the following behavior without having to explicitly specify it with options:

```
xargs -d '\n'
```

Unlike with most commands, you can't just use an alias because pipes don't recognize aliases (as a side-note, why is it designed this way?). I also tried creating my own `~/bin/xargs` script but I think it's not as simple as reading "$@" as a string inside the script.

Any suggestions how to make the delimiter a newline by default? I don't want to get a bunch of errors when I have a space in the path (and using `find ... -print0 | xargs -0` has other unwanted effects).

**UPDATE**

My shell script attempt is this:

```
/usr/local/bin/xargs -d '\n' "$@"
```

Comment: Aliases work with pipes for me. But when you run into the limitations of aliases (like they can't process arguments), just use a shell function instead.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to change xargs's default behavior. Please show the `xargs` script you tried to write, if you want help fixing it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I hadn't explored the option of a shell function. That sounds interesting. I'm not in favor of tr since I could just as well use the -d flag. So far the best option for me is to add the option to my xargs key binding. I'll show my script shortly...

Comment: Do you want to know why that shell script doesn't work? Or are you satisified with using a shell function, as @Barmar suggests. (I haven't had any problem piping to aliases either. What version of bash are you using? -- or are you using some other shell?)

Comment: Shell version: zsh 4.3.12 (i386-apple-darwin11.2.0). Actually I think I get the output I want from executing "grep path/with/whitespace myString" but after the result it shows "grep: path/with/whitespace: No such file or directory". It's not a huge problem, most of the time I use xargs with a keybinding. But it's something that has bothered me for years. I'm not familiar with shell functions so would like to hear other suggestions.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat: I have zsh 5.0, and piping to an alias works just fine. Shell functions are really easy; if you've been using shells for years, it's definitely time you took a look at them.

Comment: Thanks Rici. I will invest some time learning them.

Answer (score 18):

I tested `xargs -d '\n' -n1 echo` on the command line and it worked as advertised; breaking the input up into single lines and echoing it.

You could be being bitten by assumptions regarding shell escaping during variable assignment.  For instance, if your shell script is similar to this:

> CMD="xargs -d '\n' -n1 echo" 
>   cat inputfile | $CMD

then an error occurs, because the double-quotes around the entire CMD string preserve both the single-quotes and the backslash in the delimiter.

If you are enclosing the xargs command within quotes, you could change it to the following (no single-quotes)

> CMD="xargs -d \n -n1 echo" 
>   cat inputfile | $CMD

and it will likely function as you need.

Tested on CentOS 6.4, xargs version 4.4.2

Comment: I'd rather not use some alternate syntax. But thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 11):

If your version of `xargs` doesn't support setting a different delimiter (like the one on a 2011 FreeBSD server...), you can use `tr` to turn your delimiters into something `xargs` will work with. You might need to use a few translations before and after if your input has characters that your `xargs` considers delimiters (such as spaces) or you could simply translate your delimiters to `NULL`/`0x0` and pass the `-0` argument to `xargs`.

Here is an example of using `xargs` to find any file in $PATH that could be a possible shell to use (the reason I'm here, then I came up with another answer):
`echo $PATH | tr ':' '\0' | xargs -0 ls | grep sh | sort`

Answer (score 2):

I have `~/bin` in my `PATH` and keep a short script with my favorite defaults accessible by all shells on my system (at different times I use Dash, Bash, and Fish). It's tiny:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
exec xargs -rd\\n "$@"
```

The script is called `x` to avoid conflicts with scripts expecting the standard `xargs` defaults. If you try to replace `xargs` itself, which I don't recommend, make sure your `~/bin` appears higher in your PATH than the system `xargs`. `which -a xargs` tells me that the only `xargs` exists at `/usr/bin/xargs` in my system so I know my home directory, `/home/stephen/bin`, must appear before it like so:

```
$ echo "$PATH"
/home/stephen/bin:...:/usr/bin:...
```

Either way, as a script accessible by all programs, this means you can do things like `find|x grep` and `sh -c 'x ...'`.

If you use Bash and prefer an alias, you can also just use:

```
alias x=xargs -rd\\n\ # \n delim, don't run on empty in, + alias expansion
```

Note the trailing space for alias expansion. This lets you chain aliases. For example, if in addition to the above alias I had an alias for grep called `g`, the following would work:

```
# extended regex, skip binaries, devices, sockets, & dirs, colored, & line
# -buffered. use a non-canonical alias instead of GREP_OPTIONS which may wreck
# assuming scripts
alias g='grep -EID skip -d skip --color=auto --line-buffered'

$ find|x g foo
```

The `x` / `xargs` script approach can't do this effectively by itself.

Since I switch between shells and use one PC mostly, I keep the handful of aliases I need as separate scripts in `~/bin` and shell agnostic aliases in a helper script, [`~/.sh_aliases`](https://github.com/niedzielski/dotfiles/blob/master/home/stephen/.sh_aliases), which is sourced by `~/.shrc`, `~/.bashrc`, and `~/.config/fish/config.fish` as they all support a Bash-like alias syntax. If I worked on multiple PCs regularly, I would probably try to consolidate these into `~/.bashrc` instead.

Comment: shouldn't the script start with a hash-bang?

Comment:  fixed broken shebang.